# Mocking a resttemplate exchange

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, mockito, resttemplate

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/agreementRecords/{customerId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<AgreementRecord> agreementRecords(@PathVariable("customerId") String customerId) throws AgreementRecordNotFoundException{
        logger.info("Inside get Agreement Records by customer Id");
        try{
        ResponseEntity<List<AgreementRecord>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(smoUrl+ GET_AGREEMENT_RECORDS + customerId ,HttpMethod.GET,null,new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<AgreementRecord>>() {
        });

        return responseEntity.getBody();
```

How to Mock this service,I have tried the following

```
        ResponseEntity<List<AgreementRecord>> myEntity = new ResponseEntity<List<AgreementRecord>>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        PowerMockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                 ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                 ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                 ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<?>>any(),
                 ArgumentMatchers.<Class<?>>any())).thenReturn(myEntity);
```

However this throws a compilation error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKAxo.png)

Comment: Could you please paste the compile error as text instead of the screenshot.

Comment: In your test, how are you initializing "restTemplate" object?

Comment: Try to specify the last matcher to something like `any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class)`, I use only `Mockito` though, not sure if this works with `PowerMockito`.